# filter ng-repeat by radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter

I am struggling to perform filtering in my template by a radio button value.

My data looks like this:

```
{
 "exerciseDescription": "Take a large step forward in standing and lower the rear knee towards the floor",
 "exerciseName": "Walking Lunge",
 "images": [223, 224, 225],
  "difficulty" : 'Expert'
}
```

I would like to filter by `difficulty` however have been unsuccessful in implementing the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210996/angularjs-filter-based-on-radio-selection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467379/angularjs-library-angular-filter-not-working-with-radio-button)

A codepen example is [here](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/mJxbvv?editors=101) any assistance on the best way to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally I am using `angular-masonry` if you can foresee any issues it would be great.

-- EDIT--

The correct answer implemented in a codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/mJxbvv?editors=101)

Comment: is this a question or an assignment?

Comment: Apologies - I have rephrased it to include my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the ionic direcitves create isolated scopes and the `ng-model` of your radio inputs only adds the value to this scope, not to the scope of your controller. You can solve this by wrapping the filter property in an object, i.e. do something like:

```
$scope.filter = { 'difficulty' : 'Easy' }

...

<input type="radio" ng-model="filter.difficulty" value="Expert" name="group">
```

See: [Angular Wiki - Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)